# Past Subjunctive vs Future Subjunctive form

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

What is the difference between the three sentences:

1. If i were to play, i would win the match. (Depicts future tense)
2. If i were to play, i would have won the match. (Depicts past tense)
3. If i were there, i would have helped here. (Depicts Past)

My question is that how do we identify where the past subjunctive is being used and where the future subjunctive is being used?

Answer (score 2):

The first is grammatical. The other two are not. They should read:

*If I had played, I would have won the match.*

and: *If I had been there, I would have helped*.

Comment: Or feasibly [*If I were to have been there*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if+I+were+to+have+been%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), for those who are determined to keep the subjunctive alive wherever possible. Which would be *"Were I to have been there, I would have helped"*, in @TRomano's "if-less" alternatives. Valid, but a bit starchy/dated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes. I fully accept that. And of course *Were I to have played...*

Comment: I gotta say *"Were I to have known you were coming, I'd have baked a cake"* doesn't really do it for me. But I suppose it's better than *"Were I to have known you were to be coming,..."* and you can hardly argue against any such combinations on *grammatical* grounds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and a nice explanation....Please help me get a litte more clarification on this sentence then :
If i were you, i would have played the game.(Is this past subjunctive?)

If yes ,then why?
Also,help me to know the difference between the past subjunctive and the future subjunctive?
Additionally,please help me understand whether the first statement of my question(What is the difference among 3 sentences) is correct or not?
Should we use among or between in this sentence?

Comment: @AnmolKukreja strictly speaking, I suppose what you should be saying here is *Were I to have been you, I would have played the game*. In practice what most people would say is *Had I been you, I would have played...*. yes I suppose it is a 'past conditional', though as a native speaker I tend to be guided more by instinct than by rules.

Comment: Thanks WS2...Can you also help me with the other problem i mentioned in the comments ?(between vs among)

Comment: which sentence is correct between the two sentences?

If i won the lottery, i would buy a house.

If i had won the lottery, i would have bought a house.

Comment: @AnmolKukreja  Would I say 'between' or 'among' three things? One certainly wouldn't use 'between'- that definitely implies just two options. It has to be 'among', but I think worded as follows: 'What differences are there among these three sentences?' The point is that there will not be a single difference (because there are three things). So there are bound to be multiple differences.

Comment: @AnmolKukreja Both of those sentences look fine to me; the first in the present, the second in the past.

Comment: Thanks WS2 but i still have problem understanding that if both the sentences are fine, then what is the differences between them and where do we use them and how?

Comment: @AnmolKukreja The first deals with what is going on here and now. The second deals with what would have happened at some point in the past, had you been lucky enough to win the lottery.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some more variants without "if":

Had I played, I would have won.

Had I been there, I would have helped.